Allowing characters in eg variable names in Monaco editor
Is there a Monaco option to treat non-ascii characters as valid in variable names in the Monaco editor? In VSCode the below code would have been formatted as a valid variable name, but when using MonacoEditor it stumbles on valid characters like ö.
I have tried toggling the unicodeHighlight: nonBasicASCII option, but that seems to be something else, and neither does unicodeHighlight: allowedLocales do any good here. The red color has the classname .mtk11, but I haven't been able to find a list of what those classnames actually mean.

I'm using monaco-editor@0.52.0 (in a Nuxt4 project through nuxt-monaco-editor@1.3.1, but options are forwardes as-is, so that probably doesn't matter.)
